# Counting univalued subtrees

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

In a recent Codechef contest I had to write a program to count the number of univalued subtrees in a given tree. A subtree is univalued if all the nodes of the subtree have the same value.

In the input, nodes are numbered 0 to N-1. Each node contains an integer value. Each node may have any number of edges to other nodes. There are N-1 edges total. The tree is always rooted at node 0.

I wrote the code below:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    vector<unsigned> edge; //stores the node number of each child node
};

//i know these really shouldn't be global
unsigned long long count = 0;
vector<Node> tree;

//n is the number of the node at which the tree is rooted
//initally we call isUnivalued(0)
bool isUnivalued(unsigned n) {
    if(tree[n].edge.size() == 0){
        count++;
        return true; //leaves are univalued
    }
    bool allUnivalued = true;
    for(auto i : tree[n].edge)
        if(!isUnivalued(i))
            allUnivalued = false;
    if(!allUnivalued)
        return false;
    for(auto i : tree[n].edge)
        if(tree[i].data != tree[n].data)
            return false;
    count++;
    return true;
}
```

This gave correct answers for all the small test cases I tried. But when I submitted the problem, the judge found answers incorrect for some test cases.

I'm looking for some help on figuring out under what conditions this could fail and why.

EDIT: Example

```
  0
 / \
0   1
   / \
  1   1
```

The answer here should be 4. While the largest subtree (entire tree itself) isn't univalued, all the other subtrees are.
Suppose all the nodes had a value of 1, the answer would then be 5.

Comment: could you make a general sweeping state verification code ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what that means and googling didn't help. Could you elaborate?

Comment: a code that generates random test cases and apply em on your algorithm, set conditional breakpoint when it does return a wrong answer

Comment: Well I'd do that, but how would I check if the returned answers are wrong, short of calculating with pen & paper?

Comment: Does a univalued tree count as one, or does is count as number of sub-trees ?

Comment: I don't see any errors. The only situation I can see that might go wrong is, when you have more nodes than unsigned int can carry. In a vector, you can store size_t elements (so unsinged long long on most platforms). But your edges vector has only unsigned (int) as data type. So if your judge did store more nodes, some edges got wrong because of data truncating.

Comment: Each node at which a univalued tree is rooted should contribute 1 to the count @Jarod42

Comment: The tree size is limited to 30000 nodes here, so that shouldn't be a problem @UniversE

Comment: @Jarod42 I think that's working as it should. I've added an example, please have a look.

Comment: The inner node with the left leaf and the inner node with the right leaf do not count. A subtree rooted at a particular node must contain all descendants of that node and the node itself. The univalued subtrees are: The three leaf nodes, and the subtree that has three nodes valued 1.

Comment: After some further starring at the example I've seen it, too. But then your code should be correct. The univalue-check is obviously correct - and your count variable is incremented only once per subtree (I think..). You could try out using a pointer in the function signature to return the count of univalued subtrees for a specific node instead of using a global variable and see, if the results are the same.

Comment: @UniversE tried it, and it hasn't changed the answers for any of my small test cases. But since I don't have access to the online judge any longer there's no way to know if it actually works.

Comment: @Yakk that was in reply to a comment which seems to have been removed.

Comment: @aakashjain but with that pointer in the signature, you can do a formal proof now (with the global variable, it was a bit harder). You can do an induction. It's obvious that your code works for trees with one node. So assume that it also works for any tree with less than n nodes, and verify your function for a tree with exactly n nodes by using the induction hypothesis. If you post your code with the pointer, I could do that, too.

Comment: @aakashjain i dont know where it bugs here since i compiled and run it, i posted a lot of challenges alike to these servers and most of em were been refused despite that they work fine ! programming challenges ' websites are demanding :S

Comment: @aakashjain the code is working, post it as a c o d e r e v i e w, may would people there suggest you another good solutions

Answer (score 1):

- Before getting to the main point, lemme propose you a nice method to check your submissions out with long testcases without using a [pen&paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458517/counting-univalued-subtrees?noredirect=1#comment52779733_32458517)

first off, try to figure an alternate way out that parallelises the execution of your native code, meanwhile compare the given results

until a conditional breakpoint is hit, then check it out.

secondo, after running two similtaneous diferent methods, no such difference in the outcome came off, means all sides of your approach

are sound apart one single exeption, which is an eventual [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) after repeated excessive calls that could provoke memory overload.

Considered a structured tree as input (though, i dont know surely how inputs are supposed to be introduced to system)

```
tree[0] , tree[1]  , tree[2]  , tree[3]  ,..., tree[k-1], tree[k]  , tree[k+1],  tree[n]   ,...  
        |          |          |          |...|          |          |          |            |... 
{v1,1,n}|{v2,2,n-1}|{v3,3,n-2}|{v4,4,n-3}|...|{vk,k,k+1}|{vk+1,0,0}|{vk+2,0,0}|{vn+1,n+2,L}|...
```

tree[k] and tree[k+1] are leaves, the structure of stack is as follows ...

v1,v2,V3,V4,...vk,vk+1,-1,vk+2,-1,-1,vk+3,...

this tree vesiting is single-threaded, means it is linear calculation.

Given an example:

level=0,count=0.

```
1      ,1      ,1      ,1      ,-1     ,1      ,-1     ,-1     ,0    (data changed),-1     ,-1     ,1      .
level=0,level=1,level=2,level=3,level--,level=3,level--,level--,reset(level)level=1,level--,level=0,reset(level=1) (data changed)
count=1,count=2,count=3,count=4,count=4,count=5,.......,.......,count=count-level+1,count=4,.......,count=count-0+1=5 (data changed)
```

Tree:

```
            --------1-------        
           -----1----       1   
          --- 1---    0
          1       1
```

Level:

```
            --------0-------        
           -----1----       1   
          --- 2---    1
          3       3
```

Count:

```
            --------1-------        
           -----2----       5   
          --- 3---    4
          4       5
```

Number of subtrees:5

```
            --------1-------        
           -----1----       *   
          --- *---    *
          *       *
```

---

-The case left (where the tree is chaotically indexed and mis-structured), here is how to verify mine, and your algorithms togather,

seen numerical and timing results:

### Code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
int data;
int *edge ; //stores the node number of each child node
};
// Yes they are global variables
vector<int> stack;
vector<Node> tree;
vector<int*>callstack;


void fillwithrandom(int *n,int *m,int count)
{
int a;
Node T;
T.data=rand()%2;T.edge=&(*(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int))=3);
tree.push_back(T);
stack.push_back(T.data);
if ((a=rand()%count)!=0)
   fillwithrandom(&(*n=(T.edge[1]=++(*n))),&(++(*m)),a);
else return stack.push_back((T.edge[0]=0)-++(*m));  


while ((a=rand()%count)==0);
fillwithrandom(&(*n=(T.edge[2]=++(*n))),&(++(*m)),a);

stack.push_back(-++(*m));
}


void iterativetree( int* m){

int level=0,lasti,previouslevel=0,stackk;
callstack.clear();




callstack.push_back(&(*(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int))=0));stackk=(lasti=tree[callstack[0][1]=0].data);
for (int j=0;j>=0;){


if (stackk>=0)

        if ((lasti&1)==(stackk&1))
          {(*m)++;(level)++;lasti=stackk;}
        else
        {*m=*m-level+1;previouslevel=level;level=1;lasti=stackk;}
else 
(level)-=!!level;


if (++callstack[j][1]==tree[callstack[j][0]].edge[0]|tree[callstack[j][0]].edge[0]==0)
    {callstack.pop_back();j--;stackk=-1;}
    else 
    {callstack.push_back(&(*(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int))=tree[callstack[j][0]].edge[callstack[j][1]]));
    j++;callstack[j][1]=0;stackk=tree[callstack[j][0]].data;};

}



}





int main(){
double count=0 ;
int a,b,c,d;

while(1){
tree.clear();callstack.clear();

tree.reserve(c=rand());
callstack.reserve(c);

// filling with random values    
fillwithrandom(&(a=0),&(b=0),c);
stack[b]--;

iterativetree(&(a=0));


printf(" %d univalued subtrees",a);printf("\n ");
system("pause"); 
}
}
```

### [online comparison](http://rextester.com/NIET10454)